# Правильная работа искусственного интеллекта противника

Tags: c#, unity3d

товарищи. Сделал самый обычный концепт работы ии противника, чтобы бежал на игрока и бил на определенном расстоянии. Проблема в том, что враг отменяет анимацию атаки(если отключен Has exit time) и сразу бежит на игрока если я начинаю от него убегать. Мне нужно чтобы враг продолжал стоять на месте пока идет анимация атаки, а начинал бежать только после окончания той самой анимации. Перерыл практически всю инфу в инете, но почти везде сделано так как у меня. У кого может какие идеи?

```
private Animator ch_animator;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    myAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position);
    if (dist > range)
    {
        myAgent.enabled = false;
        myAnim.SetBool("Idle", true);
        myAnim.SetBool("Run", false);
        myAnim.SetBool("Attack", false);
    }
    if (dist <= range & dist > atRange)
    {
        myAgent.enabled = true;
        myAgent.SetDestination(target.position);
        myAnim.SetBool("Idle", false);
        myAnim.SetBool("Run", true);
        myAnim.SetBool("Attack", false);
    }
    if (dist <= atRange)
    {
        myAgent.enabled = false;
        myAnim.SetBool("Idle", false);
        myAnim.SetBool("Run", false);
        myAnim.SetBool("Attack", true);
    }
}
```

}[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы находите в интернетах только код вроде вашего на груде if'ов в update без конца присваивая одни и те же значения, то вы шаритесь по помойкам. Это делают стейт машиной.

Comment: Учить шаблон проектирования "конечный автомат", или его еще называют "машина состояний".

Comment: Если какой-нибудь из предложенных ответов вас устроил, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка слева от текста). Если нет — задавайте уточняющие вопросы в комментариях

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, советую изучить реализацию логики противников в Unity на State Machine, в сети много таких обучающих материалов. Но отвечать на заданный вопрос буду в контексте уже написанного вами кода.

Идея в том, что пока идет анимация атаки, мы не будем гонять проверки из цикла Update, т.е. нужно ввести переменную, которая будет пропускать Update, если она "включена":

```
void Update()
{
    if(isAttacking) return; // если идет анимация атаки, дальше код не выполняем

    dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position);
    ...
}
```

Теперь о том, как мы будем устанавливать эту переменную. Самый простой способ - [Animation Events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html).

1. Создайте в обсуждаемом раннее скрипте два public метода - `AttackBegin` и `AttackEnd`. Первый устанавливает эту переменную в true, второй в false.
2. В начале анимации с именем Attack добавляете два события которые вызывают `AttackBegin` в начале анимации, а в конце - `AttackEnd`.

И в сам `Animator` надо тоже несколько изменений:

1. Для параметра с именем `Attack` поменяйте тип с `Bool` на `Trigger`, т.е. придется удалить и добавить заново(в коде тоже надо будет обновить).
2. Состоянию `Attack` добавьте переход на самого себя по триггеру `Attack`, без `Has Exit Time`, и все значения в ноль.
3. Уже не в `Animator`, а у файла анимации `Attack` снимите галочку на зацикленность, чтобы в конце воспроизведения она не начиналась с начала, а либо запускалась сначала по триггеру(предыдущий шаг) либо уходила в другое состояние.

Теперь, по идее, когда запустилась анимация атаки, мы не делаем никаких проверок на дистанцию, а ждем окончания анимации. Как только мы получили событие, что анимация закончилась, снова проходит цикл проверок - если надо атака повторится и все описанное произойдет сначала.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ. Допустим я все это сделал, но не совсем понимаю второй пункт. Я создал два метода и булевую переменную, но как и куда именно добавлять те самые события? Можно здесь поподробней?

Comment: Подробнее по ссылке, там есть скриншоты как добавлять события в анимации. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html